# Weighted Nearest Kronecker Product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition, svd, kronecker-product

For a given $m n$-length vector $a$, the problem of finding an $m$-length vector $x$ and an $n$-length vector $y$ that minimize

$$
\lVert a - x \otimes y \rVert^2
$$

is known as the Nearest Kronecker Product problem, and there is a beautiful method by [Van Loan and Pitsianis (1993)](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-94-015-8196-7_17) that solves it using the singular value decomposition. In short, if we denote by $\text{vec}^{-1}(\cdot)$ the inverse of the $\text{vec}$ operator for $n \times m$ matrices, we get

$$
\lVert a - x \otimes y \rVert^2 = \lVert a - \text{vec}(yx') \rVert^2 = \lVert \text{vec}^{-1}(a) - yx' \rVert_F^2 
$$

Where $\lVert \cdot \rVert_F$ denotes the Frobenius norm. This reduces to the problem of finding a rank-one approximation to $A = \text{vec}^{-1}(a)$, and the solution can be easily obtained from the SVD of $A$.

For my own research, I am interested in the related problem of minimizing

$$
\lVert a - x \otimes y \rVert_W^2 = (a - x \otimes y)'W(a - x \otimes y)
$$

Where $W$ is postive definite. Note that the Van Loan method does not generalize easily since

$$
\lVert a - x \otimes y \rVert_W^2 = \left\lVert W^{\frac 1 2}a - W^{\frac 1 2} (x \otimes y) \right\rVert^2
$$

And the vector $W^{\frac 1 2} (x \otimes y)$ cannot be easily written as the $\text{vec}$ of some matrix that depends nicely on $x$ and $y$.

Comment: It might be helpful to decompose $W^{1/2}$ into a sum of the form $W^{1/2} = \sum_{i = 1}^k A_i \otimes B_i$. There are many ways to do this, but a simple approach is to use a block-matrix decomposition: a matrix of the form
$$
M = \pmatrix{M_{11} & \cdots & M_{1m}\\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots  \\ M_{m1} & \cdots & M_{mm}}
$$
(where each $M_{ij}$ is an $n \times n$ block) can be written as the sum
$$
M = \sum_{i,j = 1}^m E_{ij} \otimes M_{ij},
$$
where $E_{ij}$ denotes the matrix whose $i,j$ entry is $1$ and whose other entries are $0$.

Comment: Having done this, you can write
$$
W^{1/2} (x \otimes y) = \sum_i (A_i x) \otimes (B_i y).
$$
I'm not sure where you'd go from here though.

Comment: Note that the problem still has a nice solution in the specific case where we can express $M = W^{1/2}$ (or any other solution $M$ to $M^TM = W$) in the form $M = A \otimes B$.